# What is the difference between saving with savedInstance and the fragment's argument?

Tags: android, android-savedstate

In Android Fragment it has `onSaveInstanceState()` which allows to save some data for restore the state when os recreates the fragment.

```
onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    outState.putString("dataStr", dataStr)
}
```

What about the data are already in fragment's argument?  Seems after the fragment is recreated the previous arguments are also restored.

```
// set the argument
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("dataStr", dataStr);
AFragment aFragment = new AFragment();
aFragment.setArguments(bundle);

//get the argument inside the AFragment
Bundle bundle=getArguments();
```

Does it mean if anything is in fragment's argument then they don't need to be saved through `onSaveInstanceState()`?

The question: since the argument can be updated inside the fragment, is it a alternative for saving the data in the argument instead of saving through the `onSaveInstanceState()`?

Or any difference with using these two?

Comment: what if the data changed inside the fragment ? I think their role is quite different, sure you can find a use case when you can use one or another, but in general it's quite different responsability.

Comment: @Boukharist, thanks! Could you elaborate a bit? How they are different for different use cases, what is the guide line for what is suitable for what.

Answer (score 1):

**onSaveInstanceState()** / **onRestoreInstanceState()** is only explicitly called by Android when the Activity/Fragment needs to be recreated (especially on configuration changes), imagine that a user started to type something and then changed the orientation of his screen, if you didn't handle the saving state he will loose his inputs.

**Fragment Args** on the other hand are used to instantiate fragments, the args will be available even if the Fragment is recreated **BUT** it will be the initial state.

So to summarize if you want to create a new fragment with some **args** (like a User Name...) you need to use args.

But if you want to save the current state (User Inputs...) in case of fragment recreation you need to handle it through the **SaveInstance** method.

For further understanding of how Save/Restore Works I recommend this [article](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en)

Comment: thumb up for the link. I still dont feel it explains the difference of using argument and with the savedInstance though.  For example I could save the current data position, or the server endpoint used for the fragment in either the argument and with the saved instance, or it does not matter at all?

Comment: it's simple everything that happens within the fragment and you need to store it (if you don't want to lose the info) you should do it in the saveInstanceState().

Every info that is needed to instantiate the fragment from another fragment or activity should be passed through arguments. a fragment should not set its own args.

Comment: a bit disagree: e.g. a fragment is created with argument set from activity. Then fragment is displayed based on the data in the argument (using `buildViewFromArguments()`). While fragment is running the data control the view has changed so does the view.  if save the change in argument then fragment's view restoring will still call that same `buildViewFromArguments()`,  but if store the change through onSaveStateInstance(), then the fragment needs two sets of logic to build the view either from the argument(starting from a fresh creation) or from the savedInstance (os restores the fragment).

Answer (score 0):

**savedInstance** : saveInstanceState when you are frequently moving back and forth between activities and remember this thing when you close app mean it get removes from memory, information will also lost.

**Bundle :**
[image] 
Bundle uses a Map for holding the extras you’re putting into. so in this way there’s no difference between a Map and Bundle. but when you’re going to send data to another Activity(or any other IPC components such as Service, BroadcastReceiver,…) the Map will be marshalled into byte[] via a Parcel, and will send to destination. in destination the data will go into the same flow in reverse and the byte[] will be unmarshalled into Map and you can have extras by providing the same keys.

So Bundle is like a Map which can also be marshalled/unmarshalled to/from byte[]. one important note is that you cannot use this byte[] to persist your bundle, as it’s designed ONLY to transfer to components, and will not work if underlying data structure changes.

Comment: thanks! Not really feel the question is answered here. argument and the savedInstance both are bundle,  even after the os kill the app's process and in its restoration both argument and the savedInstance are restored. I agree when passing data from activity to fragment the argument is the way, but that is not the question. Question is the difference when trying to save the state and seems both could do the same.